# Select next 20 rows after top 10

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to select next 20 rows after top 10 rows.

```
select TOP 20 * 
from memberform 
where Row_Number over(10)
```

Comment: Since a table has no inherent order, by what column(s) do you want to order?

Comment: I want to select next 20 rows after first 10 rows.Isnt there row increment into sql?

Comment: How have you determined the first 10 rows of a table? `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM T`
 returns 10 arbitrary rows. Maybe you'll get ten other on the next query. You need an `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use something like a CTE (Common Table Expression) and a `ROW_NUMBER` to define row numberings for your data set - then select from that numbered CTE for the set of rows you want:

```
;WITH PagingCte AS
(
    SELECT 
        (list of columns),
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY -some-column-of-yours-)
    FROM
        dbo.memberform 
)
SELECT
    (list of columns)
FROM
    PagingCte
WHERE
    RowNum BETWEEN 10 AND 29
```

In the inner `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, you need to define an **ordering** which defines how the rows are numbered (order by date, or by ID, or whatever makes sense for you).

Without an **explicit ordering**, there is no *next 20 after the first 10* to be had..

Comment: Cant i use between? select top 20 * from table where rows between 20 and 40?

Comment: @DiH: **no** - there's no automatic, built-in "row numbering" in SQL Server. And again: **without explicit ordering**, there is no order, and therefore you cannot get the "next 10" - the next 10 **ordered by WHAT?**

Comment: Cant i use select * ?

Answer (score 6):

do you mean offset clause ?

OFFSET excludes the first set of records.
OFFSET can only be used with an ORDER BY clause.
OFFSET with FETCH NEXT returns a defined window of records.
OFFSET with FETCH NEXT is great for building pagination support.

The general syntax to exclude first n records is:

```
   SELECT column-names
   FROM table-name
   ORDER BY column-names
   OFFSET n ROWS
```

Please refer to http://www.dofactory.com/sql/order-by-offset-fetch

Comment: Does SQL Server 2008 have OFFSET?

Comment: This is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** and thus not available to the OP with SQL Server 2008 ...

Comment: sql server **2008**

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT TOP 30 name, 
       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RN
FROM memberform 
ORDER BY id
)
SELECT 
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN <=10 THEN name END) AS Col1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN > 10 THEN name END) AS Col2
FROM T       
GROUP BY RN % 10
```