# read_sql in chunks with polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to read a large database table with polars. Unfortunately, the data is too large to fit into memory and the code below eventually fails.

Is there a way in polars how to define a chunksize, and also write these chunks to parquet, or use the lazy dataframe interface to keep the memory footprint low?

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.read_sql("SELECT * from TABLENAME", connection_string) 
df.write_parquet("output.parquet")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

There's not a predefined method to do it but you can certainly do it yourself.  You'd do something like:

```
rows_at_a_time=1000
curindx=0
while True:
    df = pl.read_sql(f"SELECT * from TABLENAME limit {curindx},{rows_at_a_time}", connection_string) 
    if df.shape[0]==0:
        break
    df.write_parquet(f"output{curindx}.parquet")
    curindx+=rows_at_a_time
ldf=pl.concat([pl.scan_parquet(x) for x in os.listdir(".") if "output" in x and "parquet" in x])
```

This borrows limit syntax from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180448/mysql-retrieve-a-large-select-by-chunks) assuming you're using mysql or a db that has the same syntax which isn't trivial assumption.  You may need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267010/select-next-20-rows-after-top-10) if not using mysql.

Otherwise you just read your table in chunks, saving each chunk to a local file.  When the chunk you get back from your query has 0 rows then it stops looping and loads all the files to a lazy df.

You can almost certainly (and should) increase the `rows_at_a_time` to something greater than 1000 but that's dependent on your data and computer memory.

Comment: However, when I am trying to write that lazy_dataframe to disk (`sink_parquet`), I run out of memory again. Any recommendations there?

Comment: Honestly, don't rewrite it but if you really really want to then try playing with `row_group_size`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the easiest way would be using `.lazy()` and then `.sink_parquet()` to have it lazily sink to file.

First I'll create an example database:

```py
import polars as pl
import sqlalchemy

(pl.DataFrame({'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
                'Age': [25, 30, 22]})
 .write_database('TABLENAME', 
                 connection='sqlite:///example.db', 
                 engine='sqlalchemy', 
                 if_table_exists='replace')
)
```

Next, I'll read the database lazily, and sink to file. Then I will scan it in as a LazyFrame and use `.fetch()` to see a small sample of data so we don't overwhelm the memory:

```py
(pl.read_database('SELECT * FROM TABLENAME', 
                  sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///example.db'))
 .lazy()
 .sink_parquet('output.parquet')
)

pl.scan_parquet('output.parquet').fetch()

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────┬─────┐
│ Name    ┆ Age │
│ ---     ┆ --- │
│ str     ┆ i64 │
╞═════════╪═════╡
│ Alice   ┆ 25  │
│ Bob     ┆ 30  │
│ Charlie ┆ 22  │
└─────────┴─────┘
```

In extreme cases, since polars doesn't support streaming for some operations - `.sink_parquet()` won't work, so I'll stream as much as I can - even resorting to setting a smaller chunk size:

```py
pl.Config.set_streaming_chunk_size(1000)

(pl.read_database('SELECT * FROM TABLENAME', 
                  sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///example.db'))
 .lazy()
 .collect(streaming=True)
 .write_parquet('output.parquet')
)

pl.scan_parquet('output.parquet').fetch()

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────┬─────┐
│ Name    ┆ Age │
│ ---     ┆ --- │
│ str     ┆ i64 │
╞═════════╪═════╡
│ Alice   ┆ 25  │
│ Bob     ┆ 30  │
│ Charlie ┆ 22  │
└─────────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  Polars may have memory management trouble if a csv file has a large number of columns. My computer OS is Win11, it has 8G memory, (60% used, 3G is free), and I'm using Polars 0.20.5 and Python 3.12.

I used `pl.read_csv()` to import a csv with 62 columns and 30,000 rows. Some values contained Japanese characters. The resulting file was 11MB, but Polars cannot read it. The original error:

> remaining bytes non-empty

```
Read Test
62columns csv data (by data cut test)
rows    read_csv  file_size
30,000  fail      11M
5,000   fail      2M
1,000   OK        0.4M
```

However, using `polars.read_csv()` on a 1 column x 3,000,000 rows csv (also 11MB),  it worked:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'X': ["100"] * 3000000})
df.write_csv("data3.csv")

file = "data3.csv"
df=pl.read_csv(
    source=file,
    separator=",",
    )
```

Result:

```
shape: (3_000_000, 1)
┌─────┐
│ X   │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 100 │
│ 100 │
```

was returned in 0.31 seconds.

From this result, I created data file by removing unnecessary columns from
the original data, and I could use Polars.

Comment: Another case today, polars read_excel,
excel file xlsx  1300 rows   16 columns  260kbyte,
result
Original error: ```remaining bytes non-empty```